# Click on checkboxes based on text in another column and status of checkbox

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a table on a page with 50 check boxes and some columns, and I need to click on the ones that has a specific text on the last column. So I used this command:

```
//table[@id='edit-entities']/tbody/tr[td[6][contains(text(), 'New')]]/td/div/input
```

It worked, Selenium clicks on the first one. Now I need to know how can I make Selenium to click in the other ones.

I tried:

```
//table[@id='edit-entities']/tbody/tr[td[6][contains(text(), 'New')]]/td/div/input[2]
```

I put the index `[2]` in the front of the `input` to test if it would click on the second check box matching this condition, but it says it did not find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out ... the index must be the row index and not the checkbox index:

```
//table[@id='edit-entities']/tbody/tr[td[6][contains(text(), 'New')]][4]/td/div/input
```